# Forced to create a new Quickblox session every time iOS app is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am using the `Quickblox iOS SDK 2.0.12`

I have been following the instructions on Quickblox Authentication and Authorization [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#A_few_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization).

I call `QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:`, and then call `QBRequest signUp:` inside it's completion block, and then I call `QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:` inside the next completion block.

According to the above link, I should now have a `Quickblox User Session` after doing all of this. This all works perfectly and all of the calls are successful and I can see that the user is now in the `Quickblox Admin Panel`.

After doing this, if I make `Quickblox` requests they work fine. The only weird thing is that `[[QBSession currentSession] currentUser]` `NSLogs` as `(null)`.

Anyways, if I stop running the app on the simulator, and then run the app again 10 minutes later, I check for persisted custom data so I can see if the user has already signed up or not. When the user has signed up, then I take them into the app instead of them needing to signup or login again.

Now, if I try to make any requests to `Quickblox`, I get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'BaseServiceException', reason: 'You have missed the authorization call.
Please insert following code inside your application 
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:];
Before any other code, that uses our service, but after setup credentials. Thank you.'
```

I don't understand why it's saying I need to create a session when I already just created one when the user first signed up. I understand that the session expires every 2 hours, but I am testing this very quickly and I am always receiving this error.

If I `NSLog` `[QBSession currentSession]` I can see that there is currently a `QBSession` object, but if I try to `NSLog` any of it's properties like `sessionDetails`, `sessionExpirationDate`, or `currentUser` they all log as `(null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, only if you use this method `- (void)startSessionForUser:(QBUUser *)user withDetails:(QBASession *)session expirationDate:(NSDate *)sessionDate` , you can use this property correct. But I didn't ever use it.

For recreating a session I use `[QBConnection setAutoCreateSessionEnabled:YES]` and for chat I keep QBUUser in my Manager, and after entering foreground I check XMPP connection `[[QBChat instance] isLoggedIn]`. Maybee it may help you.

Comment: HI, I did not found your method of [QBConnection setAutoCreateSessionEnabled:YES] can you help me out with this method.